# Java 8 Stream.skip with Predicate

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there any way to do something similar to Stream.skip(long) but using Predicate instead of an exact number?

I need to skip elements until I reach one with a given ID and then I would need to continue applying filters, limit etc. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please write specific code problem. Follow the tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need a `dropWhile(Predicate)` which was added only in Java-9. Some third-party libraries provide such method as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: A more concise version is https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270820/57695

I suspect you need to write a stateful predicate or use a wrapper like

```
public class FromPredicate<T> implements Predicate<T> {
    boolean started = false;
    Predicate<T> test;
    FromPredicate(Predicate<T> test) { this.test = test; }

    public static Predicate<T> from(Predicate<T> test) { return new FromPredicate<>(test); }

    public boolean test(T t) {
        return started || (started = test.test(t));
    }
}
```

In a `Stream` you could then do

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
      .filter(from(i -> i % 2 == 0)))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Should print

```
2
3
4
5
```