# Java8 Stream : Collect elements after a condition is met

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My POJO is as follows

```
class EventUser {
  private id;
  private userId;
  private eventId;
}
```

I retrieve EventUser object as follows:

```
List<EventUser> eventUsers = eventUserRepository.findByUserId(userId);
```

Say the 'eventUsers' is as follows:

```
[
{"id":"id200","userId":"001","eventId":"1010"},
{"id":"id101","userId":"001","eventId":"4212"},
{"id":"id402","userId":"001","eventId":"1221"},
{"id":"id301","userId":"001","eventId":"2423"},
{"id":"id701","userId":"001","eventId":"5423"},
{"id":"id601","userId":"001","eventId":"7423"}
]
```

Using streaming, and without using any intermediate variable , how can I filter and collect events after a given EventUser.id:
ex:

```
List<EventUser> filteredByOffSet = eventUsers.stream.SOMEFILTER_AND_COLLECT("id301");
```

the result should be :

```
[{"id":"id301","userId":"001","eventId":"2423"},
{"id":"id701","userId":"001","eventId":"5423"},
{"id":"id601","userId":"001","eventId":"7423"}]
```

Comment: @ernest_k resulting Collection should after have elements after "id301" (not before)

Comment: Will the input list (and thereby initial stream) always be sorted by `eventId` (the example leaves that impression)?

Comment: @JanusVarmarken not sorted by eventId..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of Scala dropWhile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569836/equivalent-of-scala-dropwhile)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Java 8 you need a stateful filter

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> from(Predicate<T> test) {
    boolean[] found = { false };
    // once found, always true
    return t -> found[0] || (found[0] = test.test(t));
}
```

NOTE: this only makes sense for single threaded streams.

```
List<EventUser> filteredByOffSet = 
     eventUsers.stream()
               .filter(from(e -> "id301".equals(e.getId()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I like this one - it's a lot more concise than [your answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791245/2513200)

Comment: @Hulk I had completely forgotten this answer. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah i prefer this !

Comment: @PeterLawrey this is a *really* bad idea, I would at least force `sequential` here

Comment: @PeterLawrey btw [there is back-port for java-8 for dropWhile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570609/1059372)

Comment: This does not work as written. Variables in a lambda need to be `final` or effectively final. The `found` variable can't be modified inside the lambda. It needs to be wrapped in a `boolean[1]` or `AtomicBoolean` or similar.

Comment: @Eugene sequential is the default.

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya some one edited the code and broke it but it has been reverted.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know, it's just to make the reader aware that this is *really* just for sequential streams, I guess

Comment: This is wrong(by its nature) *boolean[] found = { false };* Please edit this answer to use either AtomicReferrence or AtomicBoolean...

Comment: @dbl AtomicReference and AtomicBoolean suggest thread safety when none exists. Using these classes are more likely to lead to incorrect usage IMHO. BTW You can quote code by using ` and ` around the code

Comment: @PeterLawrey what I meant is - this code is such that most of my colleagues will not approve for merging. I've tried using same workaround for lambdas but the feedback usually will be - "looks tricky as hell and draws the attention of the reviewer in the wrong direction. Requires deeper understanding of lambdas." Proposal in such cases will be either a value wrapper or use of another utillisation rather than streams. Thank you for pointing out how to quote code inside comments :) Never did my homework checking any of those though.

Comment: @dbl either way you would be using a lambda. I guess it requires a deeper knowledge of arrays which isn't as wide as it could be.

Answer (score 23):

Use "[dropWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)" from Java 9.

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya thx to all mighty Holger this is possible in java-8 too. Dmitry just link that to your answer and this should be the accepted one IMO. [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570609/1059372)

Comment: Please add an example using `dropWhile` in your answer. Right now this is a link-only answer and at risk of being deleted :)

Comment: @DmitryGorkovets consider adding the stream should be ordered when using this method. If it's unordered the behavior is non-deterministic.

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya if you're stuck with Java8, I recommend StreamEx library which offers dropWhile (among many others).

Answer (score 16):

Find the index of the search item first:

```
int asInt = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(userInd-> list.get(userInd).equals(<criteria>))
    .findFirst()
    .getAsInt();
```

Get items on and after the index:

```
list.stream().skip(asInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, though I'd use `List.subList(from, to)` instead of skip

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Why go through the work of creating a sub list when you can just skip?

Comment: @TimB subList doesn't create a new list, it's just a view of a range of the original list

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner And the view is an object. I agree it's not as much work as copying the list, it's still greater than zero.

Comment: @TimB maybe I wasn't clear enough. I meant subList instead of stream, skip and collect to a new list

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Oh right. Yes that's a significantly more efficient solution (so long as the original list is never modified) - it doesn't use streaming though which this question specifically asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that without using any intermediate variables. finding the position and iterate it to the end (see this question below that answer it more precisely) 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569836/equivalent-of-scala-dropwhile)